# Using RSpec internally

Tags: ruby, rspec

Another project I'm working on requires a particular folder structure, and I'd like to write a program which will test for the correct structure.

I reckon the best way to do this is to write the specification for that structure in RSpec, then have the program run the tests but customise the output. My problem is, I have no idea where to start! How can I trigger RSpec tests from with another ruby application and capture the output?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say "trigger RSpec tests from with another ruby application and capture the output"? I don't think you want to do this...

Comment: Essentially I want to be able to write tests for the structure of a folder. I expect that this structure will change over time (as I change the requirements of the project which makes use of that structure) - RSpec provides a grammar for running (and maintaining simply) tests, so I figured that'd be a good place to start. If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Comment: What do you mean "structure of a folder"?

Comment: That it has a sub-folder called 'images' which contains files with only png and jpg extensions, that the file 'info.yml' is valid YAML with the `title` and `description` keys, that the 'content.md' is valid markdown and so on. The RSpec test I've written has a context for each file/folder and it's contents so that running RSPec as normal provides the confirmation that the folder structure is right, I'd just like to wrap that so my command line application has more appropriate output.